# Leaf nodes for averages

Tags: mdx

I have the following MDX tuple calculation for my KPI in Dashboard Designer:

```
AVG([Person].[Person].children,[Measures].[Hours])
```

This works perfectly when, for instance, I view it by Team name.

However, when I view it by the `[Person]` it's returning no values. Does `AVG` not work when you're looking directly at the leaf nodes or something? Or is there something else I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I found AN answer eventually, though I'd quite like a more elegant solution.

What I'm doing is performing an `iif` statement to check whether there are any `[Person].[Person]` children available in the current context. If there aren't, then assume we're looking at this by individual `[Person].[Person]` members and use `currentmember` instead.

The tuple formula looks like this:

```
AVG(iif(Count([Person].[Person].children, EXCLUDEEMPTY) = 0, 
    [Person].[Person].currentmember, [Person].[Person].children), 
    [Measures].[Hours])
```